# Nginx proxy_pass - not able to reverse proxy with location other than /

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have following in my nginx.conf file in windows 10.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  "C:\\nginx\\nginx-1.23.1\\logs\\error.log";

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    include       "C:\\nginx\\nginx-1.23.1\\conf\\mime.types";

    server {
        listen       8009;
        server_name  server;
        
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        
        location /myapp/ { 
            proxy_pass http://172.17.122.45:8100/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;  
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; 
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #sub_filter_types *;
            sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/myapp/';
            sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/myapp/';
            sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/myapp/';
            sub_filter_once off;   
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to access app on http://server:8009/myapp/, but not able to access. Able to proxy_pass my app on location /, but not able to do it on any other location.
It's able to load the js files but not few json files and images. Showing console error in browser as below.

```
main.5e06c118abe3f1a0.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): zx: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://server:8009/assets/envsettings.json","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during parsing for http://server:8009/assets/envsettings.json","error":{"error":{},"text":"<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/><base href=\"/\"/><meta content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\" name=\"viewport\"/><meta content=\"#081C42\" media=\"(prefers-color-scheme: light)\" name=\"theme-color\"/><meta content=\"#081C42\" media=\"(prefers-color-scheme: dark)\" name=\"theme-color\"/><meta content=\"MinIO Console\" name=\"description\"/><link href=\"./styles/root-styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/><link href=\"./apple-icon-180x180.png\" rel=\"apple-touch-icon\" sizes=\"180x180\"/><link href=\"./favicon-32x32.png\" rel=\"icon\" sizes=\"32x32\" type=\"image/png\"/><link href=\"./favicon-96x96.png\" rel=\"icon\" sizes=\"96x96\" type=\"image/png\"/><link href=\"./favicon-16x16.png\" rel=\"icon\" sizes=\"16x16\" type=\"image/png\"/><link href=\"./manifest.json\" rel=\"manifest\"/><link color=\"#3a4e54\" href=\"./safari-pinned-tab.svg\" rel=\"mask-icon\"/><title>MinIO Console</title><script defer=\"defer\" src=\"./static/js/main.44b939e3.js\"></script><link href=\"./static/css/main.90d417ae.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id=\"root\"><div id=\"preload\"><img src=\"./images/background.svg\"/> <img src=\"./images/background-wave-orig2.svg\"/></div><div id=\"loader-block\"><img src=\"./Loader.svg\"/></div></div></body></html>"}}
```

It's trying to access http://server:8009/assets/envsettings.json instead of http://server:8009/myapp/assets/envsettings.json. What I'm doing wrong here? I'm pretty new to nginx.

Comment: Better to refer guide here. As you are missing server config and port config as well which are very basics, if above is the only text in nginx.conf. 
FYI- nginx is pretty easy.Here are few links to follow.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/ 
https://nginx.org/en/docs/

Comment: @Sachin, Thanks for the provided links. Updated complete nginx.conf in the question.